# Random Activity from Notification without repetition

Tags: java, android, random, collections, notifications

In a previous question I asked about how to shuffle a list of activities, pick one, add it to intent and prevent repetition of already visited Activities, and I was fortunate to get the help of a very nice gentleman (@PedroFernandes) and solve my problem, here's the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36218985/5870156) to that question.

following on the same matter, I tried to implement that exact same method inside a Notification, what I want is to show a Notification daily in my app that takes the user to a different Activity every time. Although I managed to achieve this, my previous problem persists, the `activities.remove(0);` is never triggered, and I keep getting duplicates, and the list never goes empty.

here's my Notification that extends a BroadcastReceiver:

**Notification01.java**

```js
public class Notification01 extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Notification notification;
    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<>();
            activities.add(Activity01.class);
            activities.add(Activity02.class);
            activities.add(Activity03.class);
            activities.add(Activity04.class);
            activities.add(Activity05.class);
            activities.add(Activity06.class);
            activities.add(Activity07.class);
            activities.add(Activity08.class);
            activities.add(Activity09.class);
            activities.add(Activity10.class);

        if (activities.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(context, "ArrayList Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Collections.shuffle(activities);

        Class activityToShow = activities.get(0);

        intent = new Intent(context, activityToShow);
        activities.remove(0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(Activity01.class);
        taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        pendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_logo_white)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                .setContentText("Notification content")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Notification Big Text"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
}
```

All help is appreciated, and I should also mention that I need this to persevere through reboots and app closes, I'm not sure if I should use SharedPreferences or Receivers ??!! I'm very new to this and have no Java experience whatsoever.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Titus 's answer, I got the list out of the onReceive method, but when I ran the debugging, I noticed that the `activities.remove(0);` does get called and the list changes size to 9 instead of the original 10, but the problem is, when I click the notification and it gets me to the randomly chosen activity, I go back to the debugging, and the list's size is back to 10.

Reading around I found out that I could use something like **GSON** to store the **ArrayList** inside **sharedPreferences**, that way every change will persist through app closes and reboots, but I admit that I couldn't understand how to use these methods.

Please everyone, can anyone help me with this? It's the only thing standing in my way to finalize the app.

Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by making the `activities` variable, a class variable. As it is now, the list is generated every time the `onReceive(...)` method is called, which means that you're not reusing the list from which you've removed the previously started activity, you're always using the complete list.

For example:

```
public class Notification01 extends BroadcastReceiver{

    ...
    ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Activity01.class,Activity02.class, ..., Activity10.class));

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you'll need to make sure that the list is not empty before calling `activities.get(0)` or `activities.remove(0)`.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the quick reply. I did as you asked, but the result is still the same. I also don't know what you meant by: make sure that the list is not empty before calling `activities.get(0)` or `activities.remove(0)`. Sorry, total Noob here :)